# How to deploy a project developed in Tapestry5?

Tags: deployment, web-deployment-project, setup-deployment, tapestry

I have just completed a project as part of a college degree.
However I would like to deploy the project and make it live.
I am unsure of how to do this as I have never done it before?
I know I need to buy a domain name and some server space to host the project.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tapestry isn't really your main concern here, I would worry more about the database solution you currently employ. Is it something like MySQL? If you don't have any persistent layer (unlikely) or your willing to port it (probably even more unlikely) you could use Google App Engine.

Comment: thanks..I am using JDBC to connect to a microsoft access database

Comment: on a side note, access has nasty issues with concurrency, so while your server requests might be threaded you might deadlock your database unless you queue your requests. you might want to consider another db tech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few inexpensive hosting options such as [Slicehost](http://slicehost.com) or [Linode](http://linode.com) that will let you run Tomcat, Jetty, or whatever servlet container you choose. You may be able to find an even cheaper solution by looking for hosting providers that run Tomcat but you won't have as much control. So, for example, you could get the cheapest Slicehost account which gives you full access to your own server. Install Tomcat, a database if necessary, and deploy your war. At that point you'll be running with an IP address. Register a domain name and point the name servers to the Slicehost name servers and you'll be 'live'. You may want to run Apache in front of Tomcat and you should probably learn about securing your server (Shorewall is one option), but this should get you started.